# Can't find Windows Desktop Extension on VS 2019

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019

Installed VS 2019 and trying to add Windows Desktop Extension for the UWP but can't find them in Reference Manager. Need that for Windows.ApplicationModel to use FullTrustProcessLauncher.

[image: Windows Desktop Extension for the UWP missing]

I installed the relevant SDKs from Tools > Get Tools and Features.

[image: SDKs were installed]

I did install VS in D drive, so the core elements are installed in C and the remaining files are in D drive. I can't quite figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out because I installed VS 2019 in D drive, the Windows Kits, which has all the SDKs, was installed in D drive, but VS looks for them in C/Program Files(x86)/Windows Kits. I created Windows Kits folder in Program Files(x86) and pasted the Extension SDKs there. It works.

I'd have thought VS would know where the files are since it installed it there? Maybe there is a way to tell VS where to look for these files and I am just not aware of it. Otherwise I don't see the point of allowing users to install VS in a different location if all these files have to be moved back to C drive.

Answer (score 0):

@Shishir Wondering if it could be because of the difference in the UAP target version you have specified for the application compared to the SDK you have installed?